# upgrade Motherboard O.S. to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can i upgrade the windows operating system from Windows XP to Windows 7 on Asus Motherboard P5PL2-E,CPU E6300 intel core 2, 1,9 ghz, 1,5 gb ram, 500 gb HD, asus eah5450 series video. If it can the ram will be upgraded to 2 gb (maximum ).

Comment: There is no direct upgrade path from Win XP to Win 7. You would have to start afresh, copy out your important documents before, then back afterwards.

Comment: Three thoughts: 1. You can run Win 7 in 2 GB RAM, but you probably won't be thrilled with the performance.  2. Win 7 is almost end-of-life itself, so you will be paying to replace an EOL OS with one that won't be supported for long.  3. Consider a featherweight Linux distro, particularly one that runs RAM-resident.  You can coax some great performance from an old, minimal system, and it's free to investigate and use.

Answer (score 2):

Motherboard ASUS P5PL2-E supports supports XP, Vista, 7 and 8.1. The drivers can be downloaded from the official [ASUS site](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5PL2E/HelpDesk_Download/)
The driver for the graphics card can be found [here](https://www.asus.com/ru/Graphics-Cards/EAH5450_SILENTDI512MD2LP/HelpDesk_Download/).

There is no in place upgrade path from Windows XP to any edition of Windows 7. You will have to do a custom install, which involves backing up your personal files, settings and reinstall applications and install Windows 7 native drivers.

I suggest that you create a new partition on the hard drive (you can do it without data loss directly in Windows with Acronis Disk Director or Partition Magic or similar app), put your user files there and only after that start W7 installation from CD/DVD or bootable USB.

When running W7 installation you will be able to format the partition where XP is now installed and continue W7 installation into it, while user data on another partition will remain intact.

Take a note of minimum System Requirements:

- 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
- 1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
- 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
- DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver

Answer (score -2):

Any computer that can run Windows XP can run Windows 7, but with only 2GB of RAM, Windows 7 will probably not be at its best. If the computer can’t handle more than 2GB of RAM, it may be time to replace it with a more capable system. You should also be aware that ther is no longer any support from Microsoft for Windows 7; you should probably get a more capable system running Windows 10.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: The statement "Any computer that can run Windows XP can run Windows 7" is not true. There are motherboards compatible with XP in which there are no Win 7 drivers.

Comment: @Keltari the requester specified the MB model. it supports XP, Vista, 7 and 8.1! The answer above meets the author question though is not fully correct.

Comment: @Keltari - For what it's worth, I've never actually encountered (or heard of) a board that supported XP but didn't have the for 7, though I'll allow that it's possible. If I had, I'd have said "most", not "any".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've once been working on a PC that did support XP SP1, but not XP SP2. These two differ way less than XP and Vista or XP and Win7, so I'm pretty sure you could find such a setup that wouldn't work with anything past XP.